# Bootloader placement question

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

A very simple question. I have a Win 10 machine with OS on C (NVME) drive. I want to add an Ubuntu on another sata drives' partition (about 50% of the drive). The partition is unallocated at this moment.

1. Should I format it to ext4 first, or it will happen by itself, once the installation proceeds?
2. Where should I put a bootloader? On Drive C, or on the sata drive?
   Thank you all.

Comment: Is system UEFI (all systems since Windows 8 released are)? And is Windows installed in UEFI boot mode on gpt partitioned drive? If you are installing 22.04 or before it uses the Ubiquity installer. That defaults to automatically install grub's boot files to first drive's ESP - efi system partition, no matter what you select. Be sure to use gpt partitioning not very old MBR. If drive already MBR, conversion will erase drive, so have good backups. I like to have ESP on second drive, but not required. That way if first drive fails, you can still boot second drive.

Comment: No, it's an older system; it has BIOS. I am installing 23.04, and the sata drive is an SSD with MBR

Comment: What brand/model system? What is your definition of older? If it has NVMe, it is newer. And with Ubuntu only use gpt partitioning whether UEFI or BIOS. With UEFI, you must have the ESP - efi system partition and with BIOS the bios_grub partition. 10 years ago when first converting drives, I added both partitions to all new or repartitioned drives. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR  I have used gpt with my 2006 BIOS only laptop. Note that many vendors still use BIOS as system name, when system really is UEFI.

Comment: Z170 mb with i7 5xxx cpu. One of the first motherboards that introduced m.2 socket. So no, it's not UEFI for a fact (which is also confirmed by windows system info).

Comment: I have a Gigabyte z170 that is UEFI. Just because Windows is BIOS does not necessarily mean system is UEFI or BIOS. But if Windows is installed in old BIOS mode, usually better to also install Ubuntu in BIOS mode. Best to reinstall Windws in UEFI mode, but that is huge hassle as conversion from MBR to gpt totally erases drive. Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode starting in 2012. My z170 was from 2016, I actually had to install 16.04 several months before release to have updated kernel & drivers that worked. Using 22.04 as main system, just installed 23.10 as test.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to avoid. If I were up to reformatting the whole boot drive, I would just plunge into it.
What I want is to keep my Win 10 boot drive with the least alterations. Mind that it is also only 256 Gb. Hence I wanted to install ubuntu on another drive altogether.

Comment: Ubuntu uses Ubiquity installer with 22.04 and some flavors. That only installs grub boot loader to first drive. If BIOS, you can use Something Else and install grub to drive of choice, only choose drive like sda, not a partition.  Best to use gpt. And I might still add both required bios_grub 1MB unformatted with bios_grub flag & ESP, 100 to 500MB FAT32 with esp,boot flags for future use. Choose gpt in gparted otherwise it may default to MBR. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR  If you have gpt & ESP partition easy to convert to UEFI later.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. 
So, if I get it right, the bootlader will go to my first drive (which is an NVME one)? Then I should be able to choose to boot into Win 10, or Ubuntu, correct?

Comment: Since BIOS, grub will overwrite the Windows boot loader. Grub only boots working Windows, so if Windows has issues even if just turning on fast startup then grub may not boot it. Windows updates often turn fast startup back on. Since two drives, you want to keep Windows boot loader in Windows drive and have grub on Ubuntu drive, so you can always choose in UEFI/BIOS which drive to boot. And since BIOS, you must always have both a Windows repair flash drive and Ubuntu live installer flash drive, to make repairs. Also have good backups.

Comment: Aaaaahhhh... It looks like it is much more complicated than I hoped for. I guess I'll wait till I totally migrate to my new rig and start from scratch on UEFI, GPT, and such on my old one. Probably that will be a good time to upgrade the SSD too.
Too bad I can't find a clear guide on how to enable UEFI in BIOS; bits and pieces on many sources

Comment: Every brand of system/motherboard has somewhat different UEFI. Typically you have UEFI with Secure boot, UEFI and CSM where CSM is the emulation of BIOS boot. Then when you create live installer flash drive, it normally has both boot modes, although some allow creating one or the other. And then how you boot live installer from UEFI one time boot menu, is then how it installs. Always boot in UEFI mode. Boot mode of live installer & default boot mode set in UEFI for boot of installed system must match.